# prototype: stop observing div when content is ready

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var q = getUrlVars()["q"];
    var live = new updater('live', '1', 'check.php?q='+ q +'');
    live.getUpdate();
});

<div id = 'live'></div>
```

which loads the file check.php very second. once requested results are ready I would like to stop the document observer.

However when I add to the file check.php the code

```
document.stopObserving;
```

it does not stop loading/work. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: That sounds like a method name to me, try to call it.

Comment: as Bergi says try doing `document.stopObserving();`

Comment: @Bergi and Geek Num 88: I am doing this and it is working when done from the file containing the live div and the JS code. However it is not working when I add it to the file check.php which is loaded into the live div.

Comment: If you are using Ajax.Updater there is an option to evaluate script blocks in the returned content `evalScripts` http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/